# Sorting a list with jPList clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm trying to sort the list with this *jPList* library.
The problem is that the library does it with a *select* option, that I don't like. I'm trying to use a button to order my list. 
Here on my JsFiddle you can see a demo I created, my list is bigger, but similar:

http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/wsauumra/3/

I'm using the function *.html* to insert inside the html the code they use on [this](http://jplist.com/controls/default-sort) page to sort the list. 
If I put manually inside the ***#sos*** div it works, but doing it with the button click and .html doesn't.

Can someone help me?

```
$('.sortName').click(function () {
    $('#sos').html('<div class="hidden" data-control-type="default-sort" data-control-name="sort" data-control-action="sort" data-path=".title" data-order="asc" data-type="text"> clicked </div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

using this code works, I had to recall the function after clicking the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/Danny182/wsauumra/4/

```
$('#demo').jplist({
itemsBox: '.list',
itemPath: '.list-item',
panelPath: '.jplist-panel'
});

$('.sortName').click(function () {
    $('#sos').html('<div class="hidden" data-control-type="default-sort" data-control-name="sort" data-control-action="sort" data-path=".title" data-order="asc" data-type="text"> clicked </div>');


$('#demo').jplist({
    itemsBox: '.list',
    itemPath: '.list-item',
    panelPath: '.jplist-panel'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#main_div').on('click',".sortName", function() {

$('#sos').html(' clicked ');

});